# How to identify this function? $y = \log_2(y^{-1} + 4y)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

$$y = \log_2(y^{-1} + 4y)$$

How can I deal with the $y^{-1}$ and $4y$, also does identify mean find the domain, range and symmetry?

Comment: Is $\log[2]$ supposed to be $\log_2$, i.e. base 2 logarithm? And $y^{-1}$ means $1/y$, not the inverse of $y$, correct?

Comment: @JohnD I've edited it.

Comment: @method "Identify" depends on what *you* mean (or what the question means). ;)

Comment: No $x$'s, just $y$'s on *both* sides?

Comment: @JohnD yes, that's the equation exactly

Comment: If there's only one variable, it's not a function, and the words "domain" and "range" do not apply. Please check the statement of the question --- something's very wrong.

Comment: Here's a screenshot from the exercise: http://i.imgur.com/tdv1WfW.png it is not the only problem with one variable, is it a mistake?

Comment: I am guessing it is supposed to be a function in y so f(y)= instead of y =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As given in the screenshot $$y = \log_2(y^{-1} + 4y)$$ cannot be considered as a function (I suppose that you noticed that, in the list, this is the only case where you have only $y$'s in both sides).

The only thing I could say is that $y$ is a constant which is the solution of equation $$f(y)=y -\log_2(y^{-1} + 4y)=0$$ which corresponds to the intersection of the two curves.

If you plot $f(y)$ as a function of $y$, you will notice that $f(y)=0$ for a value of $y$ close to $y=4$ (polishing the solution would lead to $y=4.03432$).

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that it was supposed to be a function in y instead and here's my solution
$$f(y)=\log_2(y^{-1}+4y)$$
for this function to be real:
$$y^{-1}+4y > 0$$
$$4y > \frac{1}{y}$$
$$y^2>\frac{1}{4}$$
therefore
$$|y|>\frac{1}{2}
  OR -\frac{1}{2}<y<\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: I agree with your interpretation, but note that $y$ must be positive (else $y^{-1}+4y$ is negative and its logarithm isn't real). That justifies multiplying both sides of the inequality by $y$ but then $y^2>1/4$ implies $y>1/2$.